# I receive 404 node_modules not found

Tags: html, angularjs, http-status-code-404

I'm using gulp and angular to create a simple web application.

When I make gulp serve the application cannot find whatever I have in node_modules folder.

Here is my gulp file:

```
// generated on 2017-10-12 using generator-webapp 3.0.1
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpLoadPlugins = require('gulp-load-plugins');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const del = require('del');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

const $ = gulpLoadPlugins();
const reload = browserSync.reload;

let dev = true;

gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/*.css')
    .pipe($.if(dev, $.sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']}))
    .pipe($.if(dev, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('html', ['styles'], () => {
  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe($.useref({searchPath: ['.tmp', 'app', '.']}))
    .pipe($.if(/\.js$/, $.uglify({compress: {drop_console: true}})))
    .pipe($.if(/\.css$/, $.cssnano({safe: true, autoprefixer: false})))
    .pipe($.if(/\.html$/, $.htmlmin({
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      minifyCSS: true,
      minifyJS: {compress: {drop_console: true}},
      processConditionalComments: true,
      removeComments: true,
      removeEmptyAttributes: true,
      removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
      removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('images', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('fonts', () => {
  return gulp.src(require('main-bower-files')('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}', function (err) {})
    .concat('app/fonts/**/*'))
    .pipe($.if(dev, gulp.dest('.tmp/fonts'), gulp.dest('dist/fonts')));
});

gulp.task('extras', () => {
  return gulp.src([
    'app/*',
    '!app/*.html'
  ], {
    dot: true
  }).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist']));

gulp.task('serve', () => {
  runSequence(['clean'], ['styles', 'fonts'], () => {
    browserSync.init({
      notify: false,
      port: 9000,
      server: {
        baseDir: ['.tmp', 'app']
      }
    });

    gulp.watch([
      'app/*.html',
      'app/images/**/*',
      '.tmp/fonts/**/*'
    ]).on('change', reload);

    gulp.watch('app/styles/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('app/fonts/**/*', ['fonts']);
  });
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['default'], () => {
  browserSync.init({
    notify: false,
    port: 9000,
    server: {
      baseDir: ['dist']
    }
  });
});


gulp.task('build', ['html', 'images', 'fonts', 'extras'], () => {
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*').pipe($.size({title: 'build', gzip: true}));
});

gulp.task('default', () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    dev = false;
    runSequence(['clean'], 'build', resolve);
  });
});
```

And my index.html inside app is something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>paykey</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" >
```

So for everything I point to node_modules is not found, and for example "styles" folder is at the same level and is found. Any idea why this is happening?

package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-register": "^6.5.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.2.1",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-size": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.5.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "wiredep": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "node": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [
        2,
        "single"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "modernizr": "^3.5.0",
    "popper": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `serve:dist` gulp task is serving the content from the `dist` directory. You need to create a new gulp task to copy over your scripts found in node_modules. Or better yet, just use Webpack.

Comment: thanks , do you have an example of webpack that fit as solution?

Comment: Sadly this type of stuff takes time. I spent three days reverse engineering a build process for a project that was in way too deep in Gulp. My advice is to start with a fresh webpack configuration and start from scratch. Although thankfully, your Gulp file isn't out of hand.

Comment: For the time being just create a new task to copy the files you need into the dist folder. Then update your script in `index.html`to use those.

Comment: it appears that gulp serve does not use dist folder

Comment: Sorry `serve:dist`